# DRF SearchFilter in ListAPIViews

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

*I'm working on Django==3.2.7, djangorestframework==3.12.4 and django-filter==21.1. and React for the frontend*

**What I would like to do**:

1. Return Job Offer objects that contains words from search (Search fields job_title and localistation)
2. Remove useless words like ('in', 'a', 'an', 'the', 'at', 'for', 'to') in search

here an example of the url:

```
{{URL}}/api/v1/job-offers/jobs/?search=Chef in Texas
allowed_methods = ['GET']
```

What I've done so far in my (ListAPIView):

```
class JobOfferListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = JobOffer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobOfferSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]

    search_fields = ['job_title', 'localisation']
    ordering_fields = ['user', 'is_active']
    filterset_fields = ['user', 'is_active', 'job_title', 'type_of_job', 'start_date', 'salary', 'localisation']

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclude_words = ['in', 'a', 'an', 'the', 'at', 'for', 'to']
        keywords = self.request.GET.get('search').split(' ')
        keywords = [keyword for keyword in keywords if keyword not in exclude_words]
        if keywords:
            for keyword in keywords:
                queryset = queryset.filter(
                    Q(job_title__icontains=keyword) | Q(localisation__icontains=keyword)
                )
            print(queryset)
        return queryset
```

Problème:
When i'm printing queryset i can see filtered Job Offers in terminal but not return in Postman.

**Terminal Screen:**
[image: Terminal Screen]

**Postman Screen**

[image: Postman Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Please share your serializer code.

Meanwhile to test whether the queryset is getting parsed in serializer or not, use `raise Exception(queryset)` or if this is correct then `raise Exception(serializer.data)`